# Are "code reviews" allowed?

Tags: discussion, policy

A ["Code Review" Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) exists currently in beta. I often see code review type questions on Stack Overflow, where the community adds comments recommending the OP posts the review on the Code Review Stack Exchange, instead of Stack Overflow.

Given that games programming is a specialised subset of programming, would it be acceptable to post code review type questions here (as total visibility would be poorer on the Code Review beta, and the target audience would be better suited here)?

I have written a small Snake game that's only ~300 LoC, and since I'm very new to game development, I wish to know what could be improved, and would rather seasoned games developer give me advice than any type of programmer which may visit the Code Review beta.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter whether a game developer gives you the review or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posting a snippet of code you're having a specific problem with and asking for help in identifying the bug or undesirable behavior, especially if the subject is very game-specific and thus likely to have better input from actual game developers, is certainly on-topic (I think).

But posting many (in the hundreds) of lines of code and asking for a generalized review of that code is not, especially since the Code Review SE exists. If nothing else this just stifles the development of that beta site, when instead we should be encouraging it to grow (where it makes sense).

If Code Review never gets out of beta, I'd reconsider this stance, but even then I suspect it is better to ask for a review in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19) or on a [discussion forum site like GDNet](http://gamedev.net).